# Should world leaders be screened for psychological suitability?

Tags: politics, psychology, geopolitics

So, in this sci-fi futuristic universe, I am trying to solve what i call the Basic Problem of Human Leadership, which is thus:

1 in any Democratic system, both good and bad people are able to come into power.

2 bad people are power-hungry; good people aren’t, so…

3 …it is inevitable that bad people will end up in power.

I have glumly been convinced for a while now that this problem cannot be solved without replacing humans with nonhuman rulers, which in an earlier question i described why I am opposed to. But then I had a brain ping, which was this: use the advanced biotechnology/neuroscience that these future people possess to track down the brain patterns associated with bad leadership, (egocentricity, xenophobia, racism, etc) and then scan the brains of all potential candidates for these traits. Those determined to be “bad potential rulers” (BPRs) are sent off with a heads-up for the psychiatrist, only the best people get into power, everyone wins.

Is this system fallible? Would it work realistically?

Comment: But who will bell the cat?

Comment: The most frequent sign a person is psychological disheveled is they want to be the leader. This has been written already. One of Douglas Adams books. https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/2416-the-major-problem-mdash-one-of-the-major-problems-for-there-are

Comment: Pratchett’s solution was to immediately jail anyone who is elected to office. Seems reasonable.

Comment: *Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?* Who will watch the watchmen themselves? ([Juvenal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juvenal), around 110 CE.)

Comment: I was going to place this as an answer, but because the question has been closed... This could be plausible, but it's nowhere near as simple as brain scan. There are no unique "brain patterns" associated with racism, narcissism, etc. Rather, brain scanning involves analyzing complex brain structures or patterns of firing that could also be explained by a million other different reasons.

Comment: For example: racism involves [firing in the amygdala](https://kids.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/frym.2021.608843), but so does any emotion. How would you know if your potential presidential candidate is racist or is just nervous? Similarly, narcissistic people may show reduction of gray matter in the amygdala, but so do people that are [stressed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2840837/). Is your candidate egocentric or just stressed?

Comment: The way to correctly assess your candidates would be functional MRI (live brain scan) in conjunction with psychological testing. For instance, show said candidate pictures of different races while scanning their brain for activity. Even then, you could mistake different emotions. Leaves much to be desired.

Comment: @TheresaKay I could see them using "machine learning algorithms" to do exactly that, though. Or try to. Surprised if someone isn't working on that right now, in fact. Input: brain scans of thousands of people along with a flag that says "GOOD LEADER" or "BAD LEADER". Let the machine learning take all of the brain scan data and decide what correlates. The dystopian nightmare future of AI algorithms running the world based largely on really questionable associative algorithms begins now!

Comment: @JamieB Yes I can see what a dystopia that would be. Them picking the next "Good Leader" because the candidate had similar brain patterns to [Martin Luther King Jr.](https://www.timesunion.com/opinion/article/King-had-his-share-of-flaws-too-1324538.php). Well, turns out the candidate drinks and smokes. Oh, and they also are overweight and have terrible sleeping patterns.

Comment: If you're asking about how to rationalize the mechanism for testing the subject (e.g., how the machine works), that's an on-topic question. If you're asking about the criteria for judging a good president, that's entirely off-topic because that effort is massively subjective and dependent on [narrative necessity](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7281/40609). Worse, many of the attributes you might consider bad for a leader are actually required for a leader to a degree (e.g., a leader often must be ambitious, just not ambitious to the point of megalomania).

Comment: The basic problem with this question is that the traits listed as "bad leadership" are precisely the traits needed by the group when under heavy attack from an outside group. Patton was the right general in WWII but would have been terrible in peace.

Comment: You could try setting up a constitutional republic (or even a monarchy) with a limited democratic component where ambition checks ambition and powers are separated? Far out, I know.

Answer (score 1):

**OF COURSE THIS METHOD IS FALLIBLE**, my goodness. First of all, what makes a "good" and a "bad" leader changes with the weather, so ignoring the valid arguments of "who makes this determination" we can ask: "what happens if good quality X turns into bad quality X while the person is in power?"

However, we are talking about "the future" here, so to the question of "would it work realistically" is more interesting.

You would first need to define some way of determining whether a trait is good or bad, and then identify which good traits you want and which bad ones you don't. As an example, perhaps you do consider "basic personal hygeine" to be good, but are OK with it if the otherwise amazing leader fails to brush his teeth three times per day. This alone is a preposterously difficult task, since what is an excellent trait to one person may be a terrible trait to another. Not to dredge up too much history here, but Neville Chamberlain can either be seen as a peace-loving optimist or an incompetent weakling, but the trait of "does not want to go to war" stays the same.

**In order for any of this to work, you require a consensus on how people want to be governed.** This means that society as a whole would have to come to an agreement on what it means to be governed by someone they do and do not agree with. What freedoms are non-negotiable, and which are OK to give up. The process of reaching this consensus is also going to be shockingly difficult, because people get out of sorts about anything if they want.

So, I think the answer to your question here is: no, this is not realistic to have such a simple yes/no good/bad answer.

What may be a lot more interesting is to incorporate this into a checks-and-balances sort of automatic system. For example, if the politicians enact policies that are obviously against the will of the people, the ultimate authority may lie with this expert system. Good luck figuring out who gets to control the system :-P

Answer (score 1):

In 50's and 60's Science Fiction it was semi-common to have a world where psychology had advanced to a practical science. Conditions such as manic-depressiveness or sociopathy were well-defined and easily detected by well-respected government-funded practitioners. Just about anyone had a good psych exam as a child. Depending on the story, it was cured, or simply managed. We got utopias where most leaders were pretty good and the story was about when the system went wrong.

I feel like The Demolished Man (1953 award winner) is a good example. It's been a while and I had to read a summary, but telepaths do the work there. Phillip K. Dick has a few where it's simply advanced psychology. In Jack Chalker's Lord of the Diamond series (1981) psyches are experts at finding what makes people tick, tweaking things, mind wipes, proper interior design, and so on (they do this for the general population, not so much for the leaders, and humanity has stagnated as a result). Even in Star Trek, the episode "Whom Gods Destroy" (the one in an asylum with the sexy green-skinned woman), they cure megalomania with a new shot.

Today, popular SciFi is about better tech with society being the same. This gives us identifiable characters. Whereas some of the earlier stuff was also about society being different. For example, leaders are screened for empathy, since it's fast, easy and everyone has it done.

Comment: If you think about modern application of machine learning, it's easy to imagine they run thousands of people through some computer to analyze good leaders versus bad and actually come up with a real conclusion ("we don't know what these markers mean, but the computer says they are 99% correlated to bad leaders"). Whether that solution is accurate or a dystopian sci-fi nightmare is up to the author!

Comment: @JamieB Merely thousands? You'd need a much larger sample size than that to come up with meaningful conclusions with so many inputs to comb through. And you'd want a _far_ stronger predictor than just 99% correlation.

Comment: @JamieB But that's going off-track. The OP wanted a plausible world where psyche techniques and scans could screen for bad people. I'm saying that popular books have done this, by assuming everyone is scanned -- no simulations needed (and I'm not sure simulations works here -- that trick is usually to look ahead a week or so, for picking the best option now).